# How can I force gnu make to not build recipe in parallel?

Tags: makefile, parallel-processing, gnu-make

How can I tell gnu make not to build some recipe in parallel. Let's say I have the following makefile :

```
sources = a.xxx b.xxx c.xxx
target  = program

all : $(target)

$(target) : $(patsubst %.xxx,%.o,$(sources))
    $(CXX) -o $@ $<

%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $<

%.cpp : %.xxx
    my-pre-processor -o $@ $<
```

However, the `my-pre-processor` command create temporary files with fixed name (I cannot change this). This is working fine if I just use make without the `-j` parameter. However, if the `-j` option is used, the build sometimes fails because two concurrent invocation of `my-pre-processor` overwrite their temporary files.

I'd like to know if there is a way to tell make that it must not build the try to parallelize the execution of the `%.cpp : %.xxx` recipes.

Comment: For this particular problem (temp files getting overwritten by having multiple copies of a program running) another solution could be to make a temporary directory with a random name (e.g. with `mktemp -d`) and run the tool from inside that.  Then you can run multiple copies of the tool in parallel, speeding up the build, and assuming it writes its files to the current directory, they won't get overwritten.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a horrible kludge, but it will do the job:

```
b.cpp: a.cpp

c.cpp: b.cpp
```

Or if there are actually a lot of these, you can have a few stiff drinks and do this:

```
c-sources = $(sources:.xxx=.cpp)

ALLBUTFIRST = $(filter-out $(firstword $(c-sources)), $(c-sources))
ALLBUTLAST = $(filter-out $(lastword $(c-sources)), $(c-sources))
PAIRS = $(join $(ALLBUTLAST),$(addprefix :,$(ALLBUTFIRST)))

$(foreach pair,$(PAIRS),$(eval $(pair)))
```

(This works in GNUMake, I don't know about other versions.)

Comment: Any time any cpp file is built, all of the following cpp files will also be rebuilt. That will cause a chain reaction with anything that depends on them, and kinda defeats the purpose of using make. Using order-only prerequisites would be better, but still problematic.

Answer (score 24):

### Solution 1

GNU Make contains the special built-in pseudo-target `.NOTPARALLEL`

Example:

```
.PHONY: all clean

.NOTPARALLEL:

anotherTarget: dependency1
```

---

### Solution 2

You can also use the `-j <n>`,`--jobs[=<n>]` flag on the command line where `n` is the number of recipies allowed to run in parallel.

Usage:
`make -j <n>` or `make --jobs=<n>`

Example:
`make -j 1` or `make --jobs=1`

**note:** omitting `<n>` will allow an arbitrary number of recipes to be executed, only limited by your system's available resources

---

### Solution 3

Finally, you can assign the command line flag in solution 2 to the `MAKEFLAGS` variable from within your Makefile

Example:
`MAKEFLAGS := -j 1`
or
`MAKEFLAGS := --jobs=1`

Comment: Unfortunately, all these solutions force fully sequential building on the entire Makefile. The question, however, is asking about deactivating parallelism for a single recipe only.

Comment: It's 2023 and `.NOTPARALLEL` can now receive a list of targets for fine-grained control. (version 4.4 required, not working in version 4.3) See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel-Disable.html

Answer (score 16):

A related solution is to specify the exact order you want things built (rather than saying, "don't build in parallel").

To specify the exact order, you can use ***[order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html)***. Here's GNU make's man page on it:

> Occasionally, however, you have a situation where you want to impose a
>   specific ordering on the rules to be invoked without forcing the
>   target to be updated if one of those rules is executed. In that case,
>   you want to define order-only prerequisites. Order-only prerequisites
>   can be specified by placing a pipe symbol (|) in the prerequisites
>   list: any prerequisites to the left of the pipe symbol are normal; any
>   prerequisites to the right are order-only:
>
> ```
> targets : normal-prerequisites | order-only-prerequisites
> ```

And here's the example they offer:

```
OBJDIR := objdir
OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,foo.o bar.o baz.o)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
        $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

all: $(OBJS)

$(OBJS): | $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR):
        mkdir $(OBJDIR)
```

I had to use order only prerequisites on a `make dist` rule due to a race condition. The `dist` recipe depended on a `distclean` and `diff` rules, and the `diff` rule performed an `svn diff -r XXX` to show the exact changes. On occasion, make would delete the diff it just created because the clean rule would run after the diff rule.

Comment: Five-year-old question and the right answer appears the same day I need it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If the temporary files are created in the current working directory, you may be able to use subdirectories (not pretty, but rare):

```
sources = a.xxx b.xxx c.xxx
target  = program

all : $(target)

$(target) : $(patsubst %.xxx,%.o,$(sources))
    $(CXX) -o $@ $<

%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $<

%.cpp : %.xxx
    mkdir $@.d
    s=`realpath $<` && cd $@.d && my-pre-processor -o ../$@ "$${s}" || { $(RM) -r $@.d && false; }
    $(RM) -r $@.d
```

Also, since you are using syntax but not features that are exclusively available to GNU make, please note that the following equivalent Makefile should be more portable

```
sources = a.xxx b.xxx c.xxx
target  = program

all : $(target)

$(target) : $(sources:.xxx=.o)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $<

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $<

.xxx.cpp:
    mkdir $@.d
    s=`realpath $<` && cd $@.d && my-pre-processor -o ../$@ "$${s}" || { $(RM) -r $@.d && false; }
    $(RM) -r $@.d

.PHONY: all
.SUFFIXES: .xxx .cpp .o
```

Also note that GNU make's intrinsic `.cpp.o:` rule allows for users to specify flags on the command line, (similar to)

```
.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

which your users may like when they need to provide, say, custom include directories via `-L...`

Comment: Consider making a wrapper script for the preprocessor that does all of the work in a temporary directory. This would keep the `Makefile` tidier.

Answer (score 3):

You would do well to study the operation of the `ylwrap` tool that comes with `automake`: It solves most of the same problems for old versions of `lex` and `yacc`:

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/automake.git/tree/lib/ylwrap

Answer (score 3):

On linux you can use `flock file -c "command"`: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html. I have solved a problem with GPU resource synchronization using the `flock`.

```
###############################
%.wav: %.txt
    flock .cuda.lock -c "python synthesize.py --in $< --out $@ --dev cuda:0"
################################
%.mp3: %.wav
    ffmpeg -i $< $@
################################
```

If I call: `make 1.mp3 2.mp3 3.mp3 -j3` - it will sync `python`, but not `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same problem (my sw signing service did not accept multiple concurrent requests). My solution was to add a mutex in the recepie:

```
%.cpp : %.xxx
    @ until mkdir /tmp/make.lock 2>/dev/null ; do sleep 2 ; done
    my-pre-processor -o $@ $<
    @ rmdir /tmp/make.lock
```

This allows all other parts of the makefile to run in parallel, but there will only be one "my-pre-processor" running at the time.

Answer (score 0):

@airenas's suggestion to use flock can be generalized as a utility Makefile you can include and use as in this test makefile:

**Contents of  NOTPARALLEL_test.mk**

```
include NOTPARALLEL.mk

.ONESHELL:
$(shell mkdir -p t/NOTPARALLEL)

.NOTPARALLEL+=t/NOTPARALLEL/%
t/NOTPARALLEL/%::
    date > $@
    cat $@
    sleep 2

t: t/NOTPARALLEL/1 t/NOTPARALLEL/2 t/NOTPARALLEL/3

${USE_NOTPARALLEL}
```

which depends upon the included utility:

**contents of NOTPARALLEL.mk**

```
define _flockCmdScript :=
#!/bin/env bash
flock "$${1}" -c "$${2}"
endef

_flockCmdPath:=$(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))_flockcmd
.SECONDARY: ${_flockCmdPath}
${_flockCmdPath}: private SHELL=/bin/bash
.PHONY: flockcmd

PPID!=echo $PPID
_flock_prefix!=mktemp $${TMPDIR-/tmp}/.flock_XXX_NOTPARALLEL.$(notdir $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
override define NOTPARALLEL 
$(shell flock ${_flock_prefix}_make_flockCmdPath -c $$'if [ ! -e "${_flockCmdPath}" ] ; then cat > ${_flockCmdPath} <<< \'${_flockCmdScript}\' ; fi ;')
$1: private SHELL=${_flockCmdPath}
$1: private .SHELLFLAGS=${_flock_prefix}_$(subst /,.,$1)
endef

## define macro te be exanded at bottom of makefiles which `include
## NOTPARALLEL.mk` with the line: `${USE_NOTPARALLEL}'
USE_NOTPARALLEL=$(eval $(foreach pattern,${.NOTPARALLEL},$(call NOTPARALLEL,${pattern})))

## distributed & installed with this utility is NOTPARALLEL_test.mk
## which instructively may be called as:
t:
    $(MAKE) -O -j10 -B -f NOTPARALLEL_test.mk # which contains `include NOTPARALLEL.mk`
    $(MAKE) -O -j10 -B -f NOTPARALLEL_test.mk .NOTPARALLEL=t/% -B -j10 # all recipes targetting t/% are evaluated sequentially
    $(MAKE) -O -j10 -B -f NOTPARALLEL_test.mk NOTPARALLEL= -B -j10 # all recipes are run in parallel (since macro NOTPARALLEL (note: no leading period) is defined as empty).
```

You can then invoke multiple different usages of NOTPARALLEL_test file like this:

```
make -O -j10 -B -f NOTPARALLEL.mk  t
```

Here's some documentation:

> PURPOSE: `include NOTPARALLEL.mk` in your makefiles when you'd like to
> use Make's parallel execution (e.g. -j/--jobs) but want to disable it
> for selected pattern rules.  It defines two variables .NOTPARALLEL and
> USE_NOTPARALLEL.  Add (e.g.  using Makes `+=` operator) to
> .NOTPARALLEL those pattern rules whose matching targets ought never
> have their recipes executed in parallel *with each other* (though
> still allowed to be executed in parallel with any other target in the
> makefile). You can also provide it at the command line.  Put
> ${USE_NOTPARALLEL} at the end of your makefile to activate it.
>
> It works to subvert GNUMake's --jobs feature by changing Make's SHELL
> and .SHELLFLAGS so the recipes run as an argument to `flock.` creating
> a lock file allowing only one instance of the recipe to run at a time.
>
> Since [flock fails with
> NFSv4](https://serverfault.com/questions/1069368/flock-fails-with-nfsv4)
> (and for performance in general), the lockfile is stored in $[TMPDIR}
> (defaulting to /tmp) (which is assumed to not be NFS mounted).  The
> lock file is named after the current makefile, the process ID of the
> current Makefile, and the pattern itself.
>
> The implementation override the SHELL variable to the bash script
> `_flockcmd` which in turn calls `flock $1 -c $2`.  This script is
> created on demand in the same directory as NOTPARALLEL.mk when first
> needed.
>
> This approach will only work when the current SHELL provides `flock`
> (as do sh & bash); specificially it is NOT generally expected to work
> in "advanced" uses of `make` in which the makefile has changed SHELL
> (e.g. to perl, or to sqlite, or to R). This is because the recipe is
> passed to, and executed by, `flock` as a shell command.  Allowing for
> alternate SHELLs might be implemented in the future.
>
> Note: it is hard to imagine the value of this whole approach without
> using .ONESHELL, but it in NOT required.
>
> NB: recipes holding a lock will still use up one of Make's process slots.